# How to show language specific search result in Solr search

Tags: search

We have configured solr search in one of our site.The site is multilingual and having 5 languages content in it.

The problem we are facing is, when user language is selected as french and any searches are performed then the search result is not showing french content at top.

We want the users current language content to be populated at top.
Any module or solr settings which we missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this in a while but this should help [Apache Solr Multilingual](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multilingual)

> The goal of this project is to cleanly extend Apache Solr Search Integration to provide:
>
> - better support for non-English languages
> - support for multilingual search
>     cross-language information retrieval (CLIR)
> - an easy-to-use administration interface
>
> Apache Solr Multilingual does not replace Apache Solr Search Integration but is based on it.

Answer (score 0):

use entity translation ...Regarding Entity Translation introductions:

- Enable language fallback
- Display shared labels
- Select which entities can be translated: Node;Commerce product
- Details for Commerce product: Selected Author's language and no
  checkboxes at all

Languages selection/detection (admin/config/regional/language/configure):

- Selected/added all necessary languages, still leaving English as
  default, manually added en prefix for English default, to make clear
  separation, as I am using prefix for language separation
- User interface text language detection: URL; Default
- Content language detection: Interface (moved to top manually); URL;
  Default

Commerce product type settings (admin/commerce/products/types/product/edit):

- Enabled via Entity Translation

  admin/commerce/products/types/product/fields
- Replaced regular Drupal Title field with Title module, and in this
  field settings checked, that this is the only field in Product type
  I'm going to allow translation.

  Product display node content type settings from admin/structure/types/manage/{your-display-type}
- Published options > Multilingual support - selected: Enabled, with
  translation (NOT Enabled, with field translation, as I'm going to use
  i18n for language and node separation).
- My title field in this display node, which is overridden by Title
  module is left for field translation, as these are per field
  settings, not per content type.
- There are no any other fields let for entity translation in product
  display node, even product reference field (used with inline entity
  form).

Basically that's all. Taxonomy term translation is handled by i18n modules and Taxonomy vocabulary has Translate... (NOT Localize...) settings - different name for each language tied into translation sets.